# Codeigniter redirect does not work in IE9

Tags: php, internet-explorer, codeigniter, redirect, cookies

I am having big time trouble with Codeigniter and Internet Explorer.

Please take a look at the [sample page](http://api.karmapa.org/index.php/stream)

It is something very simple afflicting me the last couple of days.

By pressing the login-button I do nothing more but calling a function start()

```
public function start()
{
  setcookie('loginstatus', TRUE, time()+7200); // setting a cookie

  redirect('stream', 'location'); // redirecting to the index controller
}
```

In the index-function I do the following:

```
public function index()
{
  if ($this->isuserloggedin() == TRUE)
  {
    echo "The user is already logged in";
    $this->load->view("v_stream_start");
  } else {
    echo "The user still has to login";
    $this->load->view("v_stream_login");
    }
}
```

Here's the userisloggedin() method where I check for an existing cookie:

```
public function isuserloggedin() {   
 if (isset($_COOKIE['loginstatus'])) {
   return TRUE;
 } else {
     return FALSE;
   } 
 }
```

Please check IE vs. FF/Safari/Chrome. It is working in all browsers exept IE and I have no clue why.

Everything runs as expected until I call the redirect() method - after that IE somehow can’t retreive the cookie while all other browsers can.

I already tried changing ci_session to ci_session and also checked the accurate server time.

Thanks so much for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `$this->input->cookie()` methods instead of setting it raw through php?

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: yes that is where I came from and where the struggle has started. Someone recomanded me to swtich back to native PHP cookie handling but this also doesn't work...

Comment: look for whitespace that might be interrupting it..?

Comment: whitespace in the cookie name or where?

Comment: Well, when you're using sessions, sometimes rogue whitespace can cause php to send data to the browser, it's those spaces before <?php at the top or bottom of a file.

Comment: but do I really use sessions? i mean what's the definition of using sessions - I thought I am using cookies or at least try to.

Comment: ah, a session is based on a cookie - it sets a cookie with a value which PHP relates a server side data store.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the soultion seems to be, that you can not redirect within your own controller  to your index-function and retreive the cookies there with Internet Explorer. When you redirect to another method within that controller it is working => `redirect('controllername/methodname);`